# how to fetch my Gmail contacts into my iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an app in which I need to fetch my friends gmail id to my Iphone app.how to import contacts from gmail to iphone application? But i don't Know how to do this . Can any one give any example for this.
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Did you try some search on google API??

Comment: ya...but cant find anything..u have any link ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GData for objective-c;

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction

you need to do a read-only checkout from google code, the command is "svn checkout gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk gdata-objectivec-client-read-only" see code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/checkout

Comment: Thaks for your quick response...But my little confused

Comment: @InderKumarRathore it was my answer last time :o)

Comment: @sai GData is a framework for connecting to the google api on an iPhone