# Using google plus API is it possible to fetch gmail contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, google-plus, google-contacts-api

In my application I want to fetch my gmail contacts.
In my app I have already integrated **"Google+ API"** So i just need to know that can i access my gmail contact by using the same API. Or I need to integrate Gmail API.
Please help me I am new to this

Comment: Don't forget to upvote / mark top answer questions that have helped you. If no answer has helped you, leave a comment and add further details. Others facing the same issue will want to know what solved your problem

Comment: is it possible using google plus API?

Comment: i used gmail api but it does not provide functionality to fetch user contacts, i think to fetch gmail user contact we need to use Google Contacts API....

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't imagine how you would get the contacts from one service by using another? Not everyone in your gmail contacts is going to be on your google+ account, so how would it be possible to get them?

There are other ways and it is documented online how to integrate with gmail, I suggest you research links like the following to find something you need:

[gmail integration in ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428925/gmail-integration-in-ios-application)

[Gmail API for objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022357/gmail-api-for-objective-c)

[how to fetch my Gmail contacts into my iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126554/how-to-fetch-my-gmail-contacts-into-my-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but only if you ask for the contacts scope alongside your Google+ scopes.

Where you integrate the Google+ API, you will also need to ask for scope `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds`.

See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ for more details.

Comment: I need to fetch only the contacts and logged in user profile info. With the link you have provided I am not able to implement it properly, could you please explain me how to do it. even if there is any sample code it will help me.