# How to fetch gmail Contacts in iOS application using google contacts api?

Tags: objective-c, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

In my application we kept option to login through gmail. I have requirement to retrieve gmail contacts.

In the following method i am using auth object(once success) to fetch gmail contacts by creating request with url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error:(NSError *)error {
if(!error) {

auth.clientID  =myClientId;
auth.clientSecret  =myClientSecret;
auth.scope= @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";

NSString *urlStr = @"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"3.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
[auth authorizeRequest:request
          completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
              NSString *output = nil;
              if (error) {
                  output = [error description];
              } else {
                  NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                  NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                       returningResponse:&response
                                                                   error:&error];
                  if (data) {
                      // API fetch succeeded :Here I am getti
                      output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                      NSLog(@"%@",output);
                  } else {
                      // fetch failed
                      output = [error description];
                  }
              }
          }];
 }
}
```

I'm getting client error(401). is there any thing i'm missing to my request.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23091506/1604312

Comment: @CKT hi would u please update your answer so that others could get benefited from ur answer. i have similar query and facing same issue.. thanks

Comment: Hi @CKT if have you resolved this. Then please share your solutions or suggest the steps to do. Thank You.

Comment: Me also got the same problem, but I got solution. See my answer, it's working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163529/integrate-google-contacts-api-into-my-swift-3-app/54710237#54710237

Answer (score 0):

The correct Scope is `"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"`

In swift

```
class func getContactsFromUser() {
        let urlStr = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlStr);

        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

        let appd = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let error: NSError!
        appd.service.authorizer.authorizeRequest!(request, completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println("error getting contacts is \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                let response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil

                let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error: nil)

                if data != nil {
                    let stringResponse = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    println("**** stringResponse **** \(stringResponse!)")
                } else {
                    println("error 2 getting contacts is ")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

In objective c

```
- (void)doAnAuthenticatedAPIFetch {
NSString *urlStr = @"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.auth authorizeRequest:request
          completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
              NSString *output = nil;
              if (error) {
                  output = [error description];
              } else {
                  NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                  NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                       returningResponse:&response
                                                                   error:&error];
                  if (data) {
                      // API fetch succeeded :Here I am getti
                      output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                  } else {
                      // fetch failed
                      output = [error description];
                  }
              }
          }];
}
```

Comment: what is self.auth ?